# Prove that a compact set $A$ is convex if and only if there exists a $t\in (0,1)$ such that for all $x,y\in A$, it holds $tx+(1-t)y\in A$.

Tags: convex-analysis, compactness

A set $C$ is convex if for all $x,y\in C$ and for all $t\in (0,1)$ it holds that $tx+(1-t)y\in C$. Basically, for any two points in the set, the line segment containing those two points is also in that set.
Prove that a compact set $A$ is convex if and only if there exists a $t\in (0,1)$ such that for all $x,y\in A$, it holds $tx+(1-t)y\in A$.

Hint: Let $x,y\in A$ and let $z$ be an interior point of the line segment $[x,y]$ connecting them. If $z\notin A$ find points $x_1, y_1\in A$ with the property that $|x_1-y_1|=\inf\{|u-v|:u,v\in [x,y],z\in [u,v]\}$ and arrive at a contradiction.

I understand that the idea for the compact set is to create a small line segment, by finding a $t\in (0,1)$ so that that particular segment stays in the set. I am not sure how the compactness comes into play.

Comment: Please include your attempt, and equally important, your definition of convexity for a set.

Comment: If $A$ is convex then $t$ can be chosen arbitrarily. Assume now that there is one $t\in(0,1)$ such that for all $x,y\in A$ we have $tx+(1-t)y\in A$. Take $a,b\in A$ and $z=sa+(1-s)b$. Then the point $a_1=ta+(1-t)b\in A$. If $z$ is between $a_1$ and $b$ rename $a=a_1$, if $z$ is between $a$ and $a_1$ rename $b=a_1$. Repeat, the new point $a_2=ta+(1-t)b\in A$. Do the same renaming. The interval $[a,b]$ shrinks on each step by at least a factor $\max(t,1-t)<1$ and $z$ is inside that interval. By compactness of $A$ $z\in A$, proving that $A$ is convex.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

You can show that if a closed subset $K$ is not convex, there exist $a$, $b$ in $K$ such that the open segment $(a,b)$ lies outside $K$. Indeed, take $p$, $q$ in $K$ and $r \in (p,q)$ such that $r \not \in K$. Now take $(a,b)$ the largest open interval around the segment $r$ that lies outsider $K$. Then clearly $a$, $b \in K$ ( because $K$ is closed), and $(a,b)$ lies outside $K$.

Comment: I'm really making an effort to understand your hint, but I can't quite see it. Does this hint relate to the hint given for the problem? I realize that I need to show that if there is A $t$ such that $tx+(1-t)y\in A$, then that implies that $tx+(1-t)y\in A$ for ANY $t\in (0,1)$. I'm just not seeing it. Sorry and thanks

Comment: @ds4math: yes, it is equivalent to that.